# How do I make CSS key frames play when a button is pressed?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-animations, css-transitions

I have a CSS animation that plays in 5 keyframes. However, I want to tie those keyframes to a button.

```css
.water{
    width:162px;
    height: 162px;
    background-color: #1D89E7;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.water:before, .water:after{
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    width:200%;
    height: 200%;
    top: -50%;
    left: 50%;
    background: #fff;
}
.water:before{
    border-radius: 45%;
    background:#fff;
    animation:wave 10s linear infinite;
}
.water:after{
    border-radius: 35%;
    background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
    animation:wave 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes wave{
    0%{
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0);
        top: -30%;
    }
    25%{
        top: -60%;
    }
    50%{
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%)  rotate(360deg);
        top: -90%;
    }

    75%{
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%)  rotate(360deg);
        top: -60%;
    }

    100%{
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%)  rotate(360deg);
        top: -30%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="water"></div>
<button>Increase water by a level</button>
<button>Decrease water by a level</button>
```

https://codepen.io/Crispy-Pvper/pen/abPqpaY

Right now the animation plays like a normal one would, with the water level increasing and then decreasing as expected. I have 5 keyframes, is there a way to tie those keyframes to click events/buttons?

However I want to make it so that the animations are tied to the button presses and play accordingly to each button. When the increase button is pressed I want the water level to play the next keyframe that brings the water to the next level (accordingly), and vice versa when the decreased button is pressed.

Could someone help me with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you could try would be to break the animation into stages and play each stage in accordance to button press - the button press would alter a global variable which itself is used to select which animation stage to play. The following is not quite 100% right and I had to modify the css animation slightly but I think it should give you an idea how you can solve this problem.

You cannot set pseudo properties of elements using javascript so CSS custom properties were used and assigned to the `:before` and `:after` states of the DOM element - these custom css properties / variables can easily be modified using Javascript which is how the button press is able to modify the animation played.

Another option I considered would be to use the various CSS event listeners - such as [animationend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animationend_event), [animationcancel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animationcancel_event) and [animationstart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animationstart_event) but I think this adds too much complexity

No doubt there are several other methods you could use - this is just how I approached it...hope it helps.

You should be able to modify the various css animation stages to suit your intended vision-I'm not sure the animation reverse is correct but it is close?!

```js
let i = 0; //   to help calculate where in animation we are
const stages = 5; //    number of distinct stages in animation


let style = document.documentElement.style;
style.setProperty('--anim-stages', stages);

document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target instanceof HTMLButtonElement && e.target.dataset.dir != null) {

    switch (e.target.dataset.dir) {
      case 'forward':
        if (i < (stages - 1)) i++;
        else return false;
        break;
      case 'reverse':
        if (i > 0) i--;
        else return false;
        break;
    }

    style.setProperty('--anim-direction', e.target.dataset.dir);
    style.setProperty('--anim-name', `wave${i}`);
    style.setProperty('--anim-playstate', 'running');

    console.clear();
    console.log(style.getPropertyValue('--anim-name'))
  }
});
```

```css
:root {
  --anim-duration: 10s;
  --anim-timing: linear;
  --anim-playstate: paused;
  --anim-name: null;
  --anim-direction: forward;
  --anim-fillmode: both;
  --anim-stages: 1;
}

.water {
  width: 162px;
  height: 162px;
  background-color: #1D89E7;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  float: none;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

button {
  margin: 0.25rem auto;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.water:before,
.water:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  top: -50%;
  left: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  animation-fill-mode: var(--anim-fillmode);
  animation-direction: var(--anim-direction);
  animation-play-state: var(--anim-playstate);
  animation-timing-function: var(--anim-timing);
  animation-duration: calc( var(--anim-duration) / var(--anim-stages));
}

.water:before {
  border-radius: 45%;
  background: #fff;
  animation-name: var(--anim-name);
}

.water:after {
  border-radius: 35%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  animation-name: var(--anim-name);
}

@keyframes null {
  from {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0);
    top: -30%;
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0);
    top: -30%;
  }
}
@keyframes wave0 {
  from {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(360deg);
    top: -30%;
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
    top: -60%;
  }
}
@keyframes wave1 {
  from {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(360deg);
    top: -30%;
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
    top: -60%;
  }
}

@keyframes wave2 {
  from {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
    top: -60%;
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(360deg);
    top: -90%;
  }
}

@keyframes wave3 {
  from {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
    top: -90%;
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(360deg);
    top: -60%;
  }
}

@keyframes wave4 {
  from {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(360deg);
    top: -60%;
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
    top: -30%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="water"></div>
<section>
  <button data-dir='forward'>Increase water by a level</button>
  <button data-dir='reverse'>Decrease water by a level</button>
</section>
```